# How to get text content within a tag using TFHpple?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tfhpple

I have a html content something likes this.

```
<body>
    <div>
        WINDOW<br/>
        DOOR<br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to extract the text content in `div` tag.For this sample, I would like to get text `WINDOW\nDOOR`.

So I wrote code below.

```
NSString *html = ...;
TFHpple *parser = [[TFHpple alloc]initWithHTMLData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
TFHppleElement *div = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div"][0];
NSString *text = [div text];
```

It works not as I expected. The `text` result above code is `WINDOW` only. `DOOR` is missing anyway.

And then I struggled a lot and wrote a little more code.

```
NSString *html = ...;
TFHpple *parser = [[TFHpple alloc]initWithHTMLData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
TFHppleElement *div = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div"][0];
NSString *text = [div raw];
text = [self stringByStrippingHTML:text];
```

I got the raw html content and then strip all html tags to get the result as I expected. But this method seems like a little ugly.

So, my question is, is there a method exist to get all text content within a html tag?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this : https://github.com/topfunky/hpple

Hpple: A nice Objective-C wrapper on the XPathQuery library for parsing HTML.